# How to add checked class to a radio button in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I'm trying to add/remove a `checked` class on a parent element, when its child radio button is checked/unchecked.

```
<label ng-class="{checked: menuType.isChecked0}">
    <input type="radio" name="menuType" ng-model="menuType.isChecked0" />Text 1
</label>
<label ng-class="{checked: menuType.isChecked1}">
    <input type="radio" name="menuType" ng-model="menuType.isChecked1" />Text 2
</label>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fAA2w/

There is no controller or any other relative code. If there is a better way to approach this, please share. This seems simple enough, but I cannot find an answer to this question. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to give the radio input a value.

For more examples see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D.

```
<div ng-app>
<label ng-class="{checked: isChecked == 1}">
    <input type="radio" name="menuType" ng-model="isChecked" value="1" />Text 1
</label>

<label ng-class="{checked: isChecked == 2}">
    <input type="radio" name="menuType" ng-model="isChecked"  value= "2" />Text 
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Any other suggestions for accomplishing this?

Comment: +1, but only worked when I compared as a string, i.e., `ng-class="{checked: isChecked == '1'}"`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to be doing it. Reason being, when your `ng-model` changes, your `ng-class` will pick up on that and update the view, the Angular way!

Comment: Well, this code is not working for me. I suppose if this is correct, then something else must be wrong somewhere else. Perhaps this isn't getting processed by Angular at all.

Comment: If you can make a demo I'll check it out. Looks right syntax wise tho.